# Hide programmatically created UISlider

Tags: uislider

I've programmatically created a UISlider in viewDidLoad using the following code and when a button is pressed I want to hide the object and maybe use it again.  I can't seem to get it to work.  I've tried a number of approaches which all build correctly but none of which have the desired effect.

```
CGRect frame1 = CGRectMake(-5.0, 290.0, 100.0, 10.0);
UISlider *sliderSaveurFloral = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame1];
[sliderSaveurFloral addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[sliderSaveurFloral setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
sliderSaveurFloral.minimumValue = 0.0;
sliderSaveurFloral.maximumValue = 50.0;
sliderSaveurFloral.continuous = YES;
sliderSaveurFloral.value = 0.0;
[self.view addSubview:sliderSaveurFloral];
CGAffineTransform trans2 = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * -0.5);
sliderSaveurFloral.transform = trans2;
[sliderSaveurFloral setValue:0];
```

Comment: what about share thoose trys with us, thats easyer for us to determien ur mistakes?;)

Answer (score 0):

UISlider inherits from UIView. I believe you can set the hidden property to make it invisible.

```
 sliderSaveurFloral.hidden = YES; //Set it back to NO when you want it appear again
```

You may also have to make it not interactive when hidden,

```
 sliderSaveurFloral.userInteractionEnabled = NO; //Set it back to YES later when you need
```